# In RStudio, when using flexdashboard, shiny and plotly for a visualization, how can I use tryCatch?

Tags: r, r-plotly, flexdashboard

I have some visualizations plotted in a flexdashboard, but, sometimes when I choose a parameter (for instance "customer group") and it's empty (no records), the visualization will throw an error. I need something like the trycatch() function in order to show a message when the code returns an error, or at least something similar.

Following is the piece of code that corresponds to the graph that throws the error, where should my trycatch() go and with what other parameters?

````
### {data-width=498}
```{r}

## Serie de tiempo
timeseries88 <- reactive(selected_80() %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Year, FECHAFACTURA, dia_año)%>%
  dplyr::summarise(VALORNETO = sum(VALORNETO)) %>%
  mutate(text = paste("Año: ", Year, 
                      "\nVenta Neta: $", round(VALORNETO/1000000, 4), " M", 
                      "\nFecha: ", format(FECHAFACTURA, format = "%d/%m/%Y"), sep = "") ,
         fechames = format(FECHAFACTURA, "%d-%m"))%>%
  arrange(FECHAFACTURA)
  )

    renderPlotly({
      
    ggplotly(ggplot(timeseries88(), aes(x = FECHAFACTURA, 
                            y = VALORNETO,
                            group = Year, 
                            text = text))+
  geom_point(size = 0.75, color = color_periodo_unico)+
  geom_line(size = 0.3, color = color_periodo_unico)+
  labs(
    x = "", y = "")+
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 8.5), 
    text = element_text(size = 8.5), 
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank() ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6)),
  tooltip = "text")  %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(autorange = TRUE), 
         yaxis = list(autorange = TRUE),
         showlegend = F, 
           title = list(text = 'Venta de Período', x = 0.05)
  ) %>% config(displayModeBar = F)
})

```
````

[image]

Comment: You could certainly use `try` or `tryCatch`, but I think that that may not be what you're really looking for here. You can still have input and output calls with Shiny runtime. You just don't need to designate `ui` and `server`.  (You can have both in the same chunk or in very different places.) If `selected88()` is meant to rely on input from the user, then use that Shiny functionality.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but, I'm not really sure where or how to use those Shiny runtime calls you're mentioning, would you please provide an example?

Comment: If you content was reproducible, I could be more specific. If the reason for nothing to show is that you filter the content based on user input, then it's best to use Shiny's `req` function, i.e., `req(timeseries88() %>% nrow() > 1)`. If this is the first step in your call for `renderPlotly`, then nothing else will happen in this function. Everything before and after the function still renders. If you're calling an entire object that may not get returned (like uploading a dataset), then you can use `req(dataset)`. If the object doesn't exist, it will return false.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was really helpful and actually easy to implement.